# How to create tabs in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to hide or show tabs according to user clicks in angularjs in ng-repeat.

this is my sample [codepen in jquery](https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK)  it use

```
 $(this).attr
```

how can we do it in angularjs

Comment: `ng-click` and `ng-show`

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to code your own solution. On the collection add a property e.g. `selectedItem` and set that via `ng-click` on the tab header.

On the respective generated div you can then add a `ng-show="item.$parent.selectedItem === item"` to the respective div and you get a rather simple tab control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for tabs bootstrap ui library:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/top

On internet you can find another example for tabs.
This is easy tutorial for tabs:
https://thinkster.io/angular-tabs-directive

I hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-template

template.html:

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
        ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.id)}" 
        ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
  </ul>
 <div id="mainView">
       <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="1.html">
      <!-- content for tab1 -->
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="2.html">
      <!-- content for tab2 -->
    </script>
```

Contrller.js
$scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'One',
            id: '1.html'
        }, {
            title: 'Two',
            id: '2.html'
        }];

```
$scope.currentTab = '1.html';

$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = tab.id;
}

$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
```